# Python, need help parsing items from text file into list

Tags: python, parsing

I'm trying to parse items in a text file and store them into a list. The data looks something like this:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0), (3, 0, 0), (4, 0, 0), (5, 0, 0), (6, 0, 0)]
[(10, 3, 1), (11, 3, 1), (12, 3, 1), (13, 3, 1), (13, 4, 1)]
[(10, 3, 5), (11, 3, 5), (12, 3, 5), (13, 3, 5), (13, 4, 5), (13, 5, 5), (13, 6, 5)]
[(6, 13, 5), (7, 13, 5), (8, 13, 5), (8, 14, 5), (7, 14, 5), (6, 14, 5), (6, 14, 6)]
```

I was able to strip the "[" and "]" but couldn't store the rest of information into list as such format: 
(x, y, z). Any help?

```
 def dataParser(fileName):
    zoneList=[]; zone=[]
    input=open(fileName,"r")

    for line in input:
        vals = line.strip("[")
        newVals = vals.strip("]\n")

        print newVals
        v=newVals[0:9]
        zone.append(v)

    input.close()
    return zone
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this particular case, you can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> with open("list.txt") as fp:
...     data = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in fp if line.strip()]
... 
>>> data
[[(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0), (3, 0, 0), (4, 0, 0), (5, 0, 0), (6, 0, 0)], [(10, 3, 1), (11, 3, 1), (12, 3, 1), (13, 3, 1), (13, 4, 1)], [(10, 3, 5), (11, 3, 5), (12, 3, 5), (13, 3, 5), (13, 4, 5), (13, 5, 5), (13, 6, 5)], [(6, 13, 5), (7, 13, 5), (8, 13, 5), (8, 14, 5), (7, 14, 5), (6, 14, 5), (6, 14, 6)]]
```

It's the "safe" version of `eval`.  It's not as general, though, for precisely that reason.  If you're generating this input, you might want to look into a different way to save your data ("serialization"), whether using `pickle` or something like `JSON` -- there are lots of examples of using both you can find on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: why is it unsafe to use eval?

Comment: It's only unsafe if you're executing data you don't trust.  If some prankster adds the line `__import__("os").system("ls -laR /")` to your data file, then `eval`ling that will list all your files, and not every prankster is willing to leave it at that..  The reason I put "safe" in quotes is that I think the dangers are often exaggerated for everyday use, but that's a bit of a minority opinion.

Comment: hm... interesting point. Even though the solution you provided is way too advanced for me. Although the one liner is as succinct as it gets, and that it works fine, is still a bit hard for me to understand. I'm still not use to using different classes yet but just the basics yet. But thank you regardless!

Comment: @user1518600: if you find this a bit condensed, you might want to use (and accept) Brenden's solution instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without eval, using the string split method and the tuple constructor:

```
>>> st = "[(0,0,0), (1,0,0)]"
>>> splits = st.strip('[').strip(']\n').split(', ')
>>> splits
['(0,0,0)', '(1,0,0)']
>>> for split in splits:
...   trimmed = split.strip('(').strip(')')
...   tup = tuple(trimmed.split(','))
...   print tup, type(tup)
...
('0', '0', '0') <type 'tuple'>
('1', '0', '0') <type 'tuple'>
>>>
```

From there, it's just appending to a list.

Comment: nice! For a beginner like me, this is just exactly what I need to understand how to use the basic utilities. much thanks.

Comment: +1, but you shouldn't use `str` as a variable name, as that clobbers the `str` type.

Answer (score 2):

some might not like using [`eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) here, but you can do this in one line using it:

```
In [20]: lis=eval("[(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0), (3, 0, 0), (4, 0, 0), (5, 0, 0), (6, 0, 0)]")
In [23]: lis
Out[23]: [(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0), (3, 0, 0), (4, 0, 0), (5, 0, 0), (6, 0, 0)]
```

using a text file:

```
In [44]: with open('data.txt') as f:
   ....:     lis=[eval(x.strip()) for x in f]
   ....:     print lis
   ....:     
   ....:     
[[(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0), (3, 0, 0), (4, 0, 0), (5, 0, 0), (6, 0, 0)], [(10, 3, 1), (11, 3, 1), (12, 3, 1), (13, 3, 1), (13, 4, 1)], [(10, 3, 5), (11, 3, 5), (12, 3, 5), (13, 3, 5), (13, 4, 5), (13, 5, 5), (13, 6, 5)], [(6, 13, 5), (7, 13, 5), (8, 13, 5), (8, 14, 5), (7, 14, 5), (6, 14, 5), (6, 14, 6)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a bad idea if you're getting this data from any source that you don't trust completely, but if the data will always be in this format (and only contain numbers as the elements) something like this is quite straightforward:

```
collect = []
for line in input:
    collect.append(eval(line))
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers work just fine and are a simple solution to this specific problem. But I am assuming that if you were having problems with string manipulation, then a simple eval() function won't help you out much the next time you have this problem.

As a general rule, the first thing you want to do when you are approached with a problem like this, is define your delimiters.

```
[(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0), (3, 0, 0), (4, 0, 0), (5, 0, 0), (6, 0, 0)]
```

Here you can see that **"), ("** is a potential delimiter between groups and a simple comma (**","**) is your delimiter between values. Next you want to see what you need to remove, and as you pointed out, brackets (**"["** and **"]"**) provide little information. We can also see that because we are dealing with numeric values, all spacing gives us little information and needs to be removed.

Building on this information, I set up your *dataParser* function in a way that returns the values you were looking for:

```
fileName= "../ZoneFinding/outputData/zoneFinding_tofu_rs1000.txt"

def dataParser(fileName):
    with open(fileName,"r") as input
        zoneLst = []
        for line in input:
            #First remove white space and the bracket+parenthese combos on the end
            line = line.replace(" ","").replace("[(","").replace(")]","")

            #Now lets split line by "),(" to create a list of strings with the values
            lineLst = line.split("),(")

            # At this point lineLst = ["0,0,0" , "1,0,0", "2,0,0", ...]
            #Lastly, we will split each number by a "," and add each to a list
            zone = [group.split(",") for group in lineLst]

            zoneLst.append(zone)

        return zoneLst
```

In the example above, all of the values are stored as strings. You could also replace the 
definition of zone with the code below to store the values as floats.

```
zone = [ [float(val) for val in group.split(",")] for group in lineLst]
```